# setInterval()--Como funciona

Tags: javascript

¿Como trabaja setInterval?

Mi pregunta es como es que setInterval puede actualizar la página y atender la funcion al mismo tiempo. Por ejemplo:

```
  while(true){
    document.write("hola mundo");
  }
```

Esto cuelga la pagina pues la página esperará para siempre a que el bucle terminé. Pero con setInterval esto no sucede. ejemplo:

```
  <script>
  function infiniti(){
  document.write("hola mundo<br/>");
  }
  setInterval(infiniti,200);
  </script>
```

Esto debería paralizar la página pero de alguna forma setInterval logra actualizarla para que no se cuergue.

¿Como lo hace?

Comment: No es setImterval, es setInterval

Comment: Hola Daniel, no termina de quedar claro a qué te refieres. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿cuál es el resultado que esperas? ¿cuál es el que obtienes? Visita el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).

Comment: Gracias. El resultado que quiero es saber como esta hecha la funcion setInterval. En otra palabra quiero ver el código fuente de JavaScript y ver como esta hecho setInterval, pero no se donde encontrarlo haci que decidí venir a preguntar a esta pagina.

Comment: Tienes razón cometí dos errores en mi código anterior. 1• Utilize el bucle while (true) dentro de la funcion provocando a que la página esperé a que el bucle termine. De por si el setInterval es un bucle infinito. Y el bucle while que nunca acaba. 2• Escribí mal setInterval. Intenta otra vez con la segunda funcion ya arreglé el ploblema. Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás pensando que se está actualizando TODA la página, pero no es así. Tuve el mismo error de concepto al iniciar con JS.

Javascript puede controlar el DOM (contenido del sitio), o sea, puede modificar partes del contenido del sitio, sin actualizar toda la página (aunque también puede cambiar/redireccionar a OTRA página usando window.location.href).

Si actualizas toda la página (refresh, cambio de dirección, etc) todo lo que está en Javascript se elimina y empieza de cero (a menos de que cambies la URL con javascript al vuelo, algo que se agregó en los últimos años). Si Javascript modifica algún contenido del sitio, no se pierde nada de lo demás.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @DanielBriceño La forma de agradecer es calificando la respuesta con el triángulo de la izquierda, el que apunta hacia arriba le da un punto a la respuesta, y el de abajo le baja un punto (pero también te quita puntos a tí).

Comment: no tengo ptsssssss

Comment: @DanielBriceño Creo que no necesitas puntos para calificar una respuesta, aunque ya no recuerdo.

Comment: Me sale este mensaje:<br/>¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente.

Comment: Tenes que marcar la respuesta que mas te haya servido o aclarado, en este caso, por que no hay una respuesta exacta. Con el tick que aparece en cada respuesta que te hicieron no en las flechita, solo puedes selecionar una. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede por que setInterval es asincrono, entonces se ejecuta el el codigo completo sin frenar en el setInterval y luego, con los milisegundos que le pones como parametro, el setInterval ejecuta y repite la funcion que le pasaste en el otro parametro.
Es parecido a delegarle la tarea a un hilo

Comment: Por eso me pareció extraño pues javascript es monohilo por lo que no puede crear otro hilo y con setInterval se cumple las mismas funciones que crear otro hilo en java para android. Gracias por la respuesta.